# Google Admob Test Device Error

Tags: ios, swift, admob, ads

I am new with adding ads to my mobile apps and I am getting started with a Google tutorial on adding admob to my iOS app. I've followed their instructions but am running into an error when building my app. I would like to simply have one interstitial ad showing on my app for all users. I am using my publisher ID from Google admob. Here is my code:

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  Tic Tac Toe
//  Created by Benjamin Emdon on 2015-05-20.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Ben Emdon.
import UIKit

import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

@IBOutlet var singleplayerButton: DesignableButton!
@IBOutlet var multiplayerButton: DesignableButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-6066036695047095/8503439166"

    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self

    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()

    self.bannerView.loadRequest(request.testDevices = ["9dbd8b758950edd3a2ca208ce50bcca3"])

        }

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    singleplayerButton.animation = "slideRight"
    singleplayerButton.animate()
    multiplayerButton.animation  = "slideLeft"
    multiplayerButton.animate()

}

}
```

I receive the error on the line where the testDevice number is. Here is the error given: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'GADRequest!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the code to:

```
let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = ["9dbd8b758950edd3a2ca208ce50bcca3"]
self.bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```

you are making an assignment in the function call, you should do this and then just pass the request object in

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly! Now, I can see it says I am displaying a test add from Google Admob. If I published my app as is now with your revised edit of the code, will ads show for all new users or for only my test device? Im simple, I would like to republish this game simply showing one 320 x 50 ad on the view controller scene. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It would only show the test ad for you, you need to remove this line  `request.testDevices = ["9dbd8b758950edd3a2ca208ce50bcca3"]` before pushing it live to receive actual ads if I remember rightly. Might be something worthwhlie testing in TestFlight

Comment: Just removed it and the app builds fine but no ads display at all now.

Comment: Do you have any ads targeted/serving? check your console window in xcode for any errors/warnings. If it works with the test devices set and shows the test ad unit then it should be setup properly, just seems like no ads are serving.

Comment: I'm a beginner so forgive me for not understanding but what do you mean check your console window? I don't have any errors just a few warnings regarding certain code that Swift 3 is going to be doing away with but no errors in regards to the admit setup. I am simply looking to make sure ads will run when I publish to the app store so that I don't have a blank app. In the past when testing I would see the ads show but after removing that line you suggested I move nothing shows up.

Comment: I just tried running the demo banner view application from the admob documentation and it worked fine and shown an add, then I updated it to use the adUnitID you are using above and got no ads. Check that your account is setup properly and is active. as there are no ads being returned for that particular ad unit ID

Comment: made sure the ad unit was setup correctly, ran the code again and still nothing. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: try the Ad Unit ID from the demo application: `bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
  bannerView.rootViewController = self
  bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
`

Comment: I know that one will work but how can I get my publisher id to work so I can publish the app live? I want to be sure the ads show for all devices not just test ones or a demo app

Comment: by checking that one and seeing if it works then you isolate your issue. if it works then you know  your ios setup is fine, the issue then remains with your admob account, unfortunately there isn't much I can do on that part.

Comment: I just ran the code again and I'm still getting "To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices" how can I modify the code so that it isn't looking for test devices? or better yet, why is it displaying "test ads" instead of live ads?

Comment: it only displays test ads when you register test devices and those devices are using the application. I have an app i'm working on now that uses similar ads and although I have ads showing I still get that warning when running in the simulator

Comment: So will ads display if I published this live to the App Store?

Comment: no, my ads show all the time...  you need to do some delivery diagnostics and ensure that your ads are setup to serve correctly. My ads are served through Google DFP. I setup an ad exchange, creatives, sizing, targeting etc. it could be any number of things why you ads are not serving. We have resolved your ios query as to why the code wasn't running. now you need help with serving ads on your ad platform. I dont think stackoverflow is the place for it. maybe you can log an issue on the support forums for your ad network/provider and then link to it here